# Codename One: Use Google Calendar

Tags: codenameone

I'd like to access the Google Calendar of a user after Login, since I want to mirror certain labeled events in my Apps event class.

I guess the Google Calendar API Java Library can't be simply used here, so I was sent to [this Library](https://github.com/chen-fishbein/codenameone-calendar) by the Codename One Support.

Does anyone have experience or Code examples for this Library? 
How did you guys handle access to Google Calendar API if not with this library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some of the initial work on that but haven't kept up with the changes done by the other authors so I can't say I have actual experience with this library...

From the code something like this should work:

```
DeviceCalendar dc = DeviceCalendar.getInstance();
if(!dc.hasPermissions()) {
    // show message 
    return;
}
String calName = Preferences.get("selectedCalendar", null);
if(calName == null) {
    Collection<String> calendarNames = dc.getCalendars()
    calName = promptUserToPickCalendar(calendarNames);
    if(calName == null) {
       return;
    }
    Preferences.set("selectedCalendar", calName);
}
String calId = dc.openCalendar(calName, false);
Collection<EventInfo> events = dc.getEvents(calId, startDate, endDate);
// merge your events then use removeEvent/saveEvent respectively to apply your changes
```

Comment: For this to work on Android, you need to add this build hint `android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android\:name\="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/> <uses-permission android\:name\="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>`

Comment: Correction: `android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>`

Comment: Is this for using the Android Device Calendar or can I use this on iOS to get data out of someones google calendar? The DeviceCalendar.getInstance(); looks more like it is using the os' calendar rather than the one from a google account, does someone know about this?

Comment: Yes it uses the OS calendar not explicitly Google's. Normally on iOS if I'm a Google calendar user I would bind the native OS to the Google calendar sync. There is no explicit support for the Google calendar but you can probably get it to work via a webservice